# Type of Question

Tags: questions

If one asks a question about the "Type of Questions" he/she might get an answer of:

1. Open Questions.
2. Closed Questions.

Or might get an answer of:

1. Factual
2. Convergent
3. Divergent
4. Evaluative
5. Combinations

or other answers.

My questions is what do you call the questions that contain unhappiness, denial, reprimanding or refusal behavior in them such as:

1. Why Mark is handing this project
   Meaning Mark has nothing to do with this project why is he doing it.
2. How did we get to this point?

Do you feel what is in the question. The asking person does want to want to know the process of getting to this point rather he wants to know how did screw up?

What do we call those type of questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could be looking for the term **negative assertion**.  From the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhetorical_question#Negative_assertions) on it:

> In the example, *What have the Romans ever done for us?* (Monty Python's Life of Brian) the question functions as a **negative assertion**. It is intended to mean *The Romans have never done anything for us!*